# Printing different sentences depending on user input

Tags: java, printing, if-statement, input

I am wondering how to print a particular sentence depending on user input.

In the scenario below, if the user enters "B" I would like to print the words "You have selected B" however if the user selects C I would like to print the word "You have selected C".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Trial extends Register
{

    //I want to load the register which will be option B

    public static void main (String[] args)
     {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter A to make a purchase & receive your change");
        System.out.println("Enter B to load the Register");
        System.out.println("Enter C to write the contents of the Register to a 
        web Page");
        System.out.println("Enter D to exit the program"); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java 7+, you can use a [switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

If you use an earlier vrsion, you need to use several [if statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

As for the Scanner, you can read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) to get started and have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966599/java-scanner-string-input).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
String input = // read input from scanner;
if(input.length() == 1) {
    switch(input.charAt(0)) {
    case 'A':
        // make purchase
        break;
    case 'B':
            // load register
            break;
    // Similarly case C and D
    default:
            // possibly invalid input as well

    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
}
```