# How to Solve scanner class using error in Java?

Tags: java.util.scanner

I have this code input getting using Scanner Class. When ever I run this code it stores only first two values. I can't enter the third variable value.

```
 //Input Code
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Input
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 try{
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
 int i;
float f;
String str;
 System.out.println("Enter the Integer value"); //getting.   
 input from user
 i=s.nextInt();   //store the use entered value
 System.out.println("Enter the Float value");
f=s.nextFloat();
System.out.println("Enter the String value");
str=s.nextLine();
 System.out.println("\nInt: "+i+"\nFloat: "+f+"\nString 
 "+str);  //print the final result
 }
  catch(Exception e)
 {
 System.out.print(e);   
 }
 }
 }
```

------end------

> Output:
>   Enter the Integer value
>   4
>   Enter the Float value
>   4.4
>   Enter the String value
>
> Int 4
>   Float 4.10
>   String

Comment: Check this —> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966599/java-scanner-string-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly change s.nextline()  to s.next(). For more details, you can refer below complete code

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      int i;
      float f;
      String str;
      System.out.println("Enter the Integer value"); // getting.
      // input from user
      i = s.nextInt(); // store the use entered value
      System.out.println("Enter the Float value");
      f = s.nextFloat();
      System.out.println("Enter the String value");
      str = s.next();
      System.out.println("\nInt: " + i + "\nFloat: " + f + "\nString  " + str); // print the final result
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.print(e);
    }
  }
}
```